# Call Javascript API from JAVA web service

Tags: javascript, java, database, web-services

Is it possible? The JS library would be used to fetch data from databases.

The web service would send back the data to the sender (a JAVA binary run from a user PC).

It would be something like this:

PC user/binary sends an SQL query with its id to a web service located in the cloud.

The web service checks several things and then proceed to use the JS API in order to fetch the data from the databases.

The data is then returned to the user.

The point would be to have a generic JS API accessing databases and executing SQL queries located in the cloud and returning data to a user.

Comment: A web API is not Java, JS or anything. It's just a specification. If you have a JS-based server and a Java-based client exchanging JSON data, that's fine. You probably won't be able to (easily) send binary data, but if your exchange format is text-based (json, xml...) then it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how you expect to integrate between the Java and JavaScript code. There are approaches such as embedding the Rhino JavaScript engine in your java application - the two languages can then interact.

I wonder why you need the Java layer at all. You want to exploit your JavaScript to Database capability, so you could expose a service directly from JavaScript. You could use node.js and its express module for that.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. The Rhino JavaScript Engine seems interesting and might be a solution. Thanks.


You may be right about the Java layer. Actually, I'm doing a proof-of-concept. The Java layer might not be useful if the web service features are included within the JS library. However, we would probably use this library for other projects, so I think it's for the best if they are separated. Also, the language of the web service doesn't necessarily needs to be Java. I'm considering using C++, if such an Engine like Rhino is available for it.